# I can ping my site, but get timed out in browser. (Only on my windows desktop)

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ping, cache

I have a site and it works for everyone and on all my devices except my windows desktop. (works on the same machine if I boot on linux). I can ping it from the command line with no problem, but I can't access it from  a browser( It keeps timing out)
The other weird thing is that it works randomly from time to times, but only for small amount of times (5-10min).
Any clue what could cause that?
DNS flush doesn't fix it

Comment: Try opening up dev tools in your browser and watch the network traffic tab for what is timing out. That should narrow down your troubleshooting at least

Comment: Thanks it's working right now, but will do when it's not and I will update the post.

Comment: If ping (i.e. ICMP Echo) works but HTTP (i.e a TCP connection) doesn't, it's usually things like firewalls blocking TCP but not ICMP, or your web server software wasn't running. It would be interesting to know whether TCP failed to establish a connection, or if the TCP connection was established, but the HTTP request/response failed. One way to double-check would be to use a telnet tool to telnet to port 80, and then hand-type your own GET request (it's easy, and there are tutorials online on how to do this), and see if you get a response.

Comment: It's been working for about 17 hours for the first time, I don't remember having made a change to anything since it started working ... I'll definitely checkout what you suggested @Spiff if I encounter more issues later. Thanks **EDIT: I do remember changing my network from public to private in the windows settings around the time it started working. Not sure why it was public in the first place, I must have miss clicked when I was setting it up. I'm not sure why that would cause an issue tho.**